# New line using wsprintf

Tags: c, printf

I have to print a message using `wsprintf`. I want to print it on different lines and I use `'\n'` but it doesn't work.
This is the code sample:

```
BYTE lbal = __inp(commandblock + ATA_LBA_LOW);
BYTE lbam = __inp(commandblock + ATA_LBA_MID);
BYTE lbah = __inp(commandblock + ATA_LBA_HIGH);
BYTE secc = __inp(commandblock + ATA_SECT_CNT);

wsprintf(szBuffer[cLine++], "lbal is %08x \n lbam is %08x \n lbah is %08x \n secc is %08x.", lbal, lbam, lbah, secc);
```

Comment: wsprintf prints the formatted text into string. How can you see the new line? Are you printing the string later?

Comment: I am printing it and I want to appear on different lines. Maybe it isn't possible with `wsprintf`, I don't know

Comment: My guess it \n is totally stored as "four bytes", because you are using the wide strings. If it is a sprintf, it will work. I think, this direction of thinking will help you. When printing, your new line is not new line any more because wsprintf stored additional byte in between.

Comment: I suggest you to see the binary representation of the szBuffer to verify this

Answer (score 0):

`wsprintf` is a Windows function. Try using `\r\n` instead of `\n`.

Comment: How do you print szBuffer contents later?

Comment: I don't. I use it to go to the next line because they are a lot of others line to be printed. The only solution I have found is:  `wsprintf(szBuffer[cLine++], "lbah is %02x", lbah);                                
 wsprintf(szBuffer[cLine++], "lbam is %02x", lbam);                               
 wsprintf(szBuffer[cLine++], "lbal is %02x", lbal);                                   
 wsprintf(szBuffer[cLine++], "secc is %02x", secc);`

Comment: `wsprintf` only puts resulting string in buffer pointed by 1st argument, and does not print it on screen/printer/to log file/etc. There must be another function responsible for doing this, and looks that it does not handle new line characters or removes them. I am asking for that function.

Answer (score 0):

Use `std::wcout`,  because it is stored as two bytes for `"/"` and two bytes for `n`. If you use `std::cout` then the additional byte causes the cout not to interpret it as new line.